# Substring not refers to the given String exception in C#

Tags: c#

I'm making simple program in C# just for fun, where I'm coding simple HEX to String -translation method like this:

```cs
 private String translate(String hex)
 {
     StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();

     int i = 0;
     while (i+2 <= hex.Length)
     {
         String str = hex.Substring(i, i + 2);
         output.Append((char)Convert.ToInt32(str, 16));
         i += 2;
     }
```

Every time when I'm running the application, I'm getting unhandled exception "Out of ranges and bounds", and getting message, that index and point of Substring method parameters have to refer to some point of hex -String. I did the if -statement before Substring -method line with conditions true only if i +2 is smaller or equal to hex.Length, but this did not work properly. My application works properly, when I'm using only one byte HEX input String meaning one ASCII -character. Can anyone help me with this that I could go forward with my project?

Comment: When you're confused about the behavior of your code, the best thing to do is set a [breakpoint](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s5p4.html) in your code and then step through the code line by line, examining the values of the variables as you go.

Comment: Second argument to `Substring` is character count, not ending index. Also, your `<=` check should probably be `<` instead.

Comment: Also look at the signature for `Substring` - the inputs are starting point and _length_, not starting index and ending index.

Comment: Yeah! As I told and commented in the first answer, I probaly have to take a look at the MSDN API:s at Microsoft before posting my simple novice -mistakes here on Stack Overflow forum. I was so Java - minded...

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
hex.Substring(i, 2)
```

The second argument in Substring is `length`, not `end`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Perhaps it's better to check Microsoft MSDN -API:s before posting. My programming teachers have gotten me more Java -brained than C -Sharpy minded. I was so in Java in this case. Thanks for everyone for answering! This was the solution for out of bounds -exception in this case.